# how to get print result in browser

Tags: javascript, printing

I'm currently developing a website that use user printer. And I'm looking for a hook that I can use to know user click the confirm or cancel in print dialog(or print preview window).
the onafterprint method will trigger before user click confirm on firefox but after user click on chrome so I guess it's not an option.

I do the print in iframe and I don't know it effect or not.

here is the code that I use

```
    this.iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(this.iframe);
//put some image in the iframe
    let image = new Image();
    image.src='imageUrl';
    this.iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(image);
    this.iframe.contentWindow.onafterprint = (event) =>{
      console.log(event)
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(this.iframe);
    }
```

I'm looking for a hook that I can get print result.(User clicked confirm or cancel)

Here is a firefox print dialog. And I want to know did user clicked Print button or Cancel.
[picture for print dialog][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlFMz.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - How to tell if window.print() was successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433242/javascript-how-to-tell-if-window-print-was-successful)

Comment: I see, it kinda answer my question. But I'm looking for a reply from browser, not from OS.

Comment: browser doesn't know if printing suceeded

Comment: But browser know user clicked Print or cancel.
It is important to know especially for diagnosis problem. You can tell user the job has send to printer, if printing is not success, it's the printer problem.